# Помогите достать данные через xpath с сайта

Tags: xpath, google-spreadsheet

не могу достать данные с сайта [обменки](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4RKU.png)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4RKU.png): http://gorlovka-obmenka.mozello.com/. На данный момент получилось вытянуть данные в виде  строки типа- "***Розница                    04.05.2020         Покупка      ПродажаUSD***  " и тд. Использовал код "//div[@ class='moze-wysiwyg-editor']` Нужно найти непосредственно цифры курса валют.

[image: Результат в Гугл Таблицах]

Answer (score 0):

```
'/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/p/i/b/text()'
```

Попробуй вот так